# Sending and receiving checkbox data to and from SQL w/PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, checkbox

I am trying to figure out the SQL code that I would need to pass an array of checkbox data to sql, and then pull the same array back out of sql for a form afterwards.  I received some help from a friend on how to save the data into an array, but do not know the best practice to pull the array from SQL in the form of checkbox data.

This is what I have so far for my form :

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                            <label class="btn btn-default active">User1
                            <input type="checkbox" name="salesman[]" value="User1" <?= in_array('User1', $invoice['Invoice']['salesman']) ? '' : '' ?> autocomplete="off">
                            </label>
                            <label class="btn btn-default active">User2
                            <input type="checkbox" name="salesman[]" value="User2" <?= in_array('User2', $invoice['Invoice']['salesman']) ? '' : '' ?> autocomplete="off">
                            </label>
```

This is how I can pull NON-ARRAY data, looking for correct code for the array :

```
$salesman = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, trim( $data['data']['Invoice']['salesman'] ) );
```

Code found in web similar concept :

```
 <?
        $childarr = explode(",", $row["children_pref"]);    
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="children_pref[]" value="0" <?=(in_array('0',$childarr))?('checked'):('');?> >None<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="children_pref[]" value="1" <?=(in_array('1',$childarr))?('checked'):('');?>> 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="children_pref[]" value="2" <?=(in_array('2',$childarr))?('checked'):('');?>> 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="children_pref[]" value="3" <?=(in_array('3',$childarr))?('checked'):('');?>> 3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="children_pref[]" value="4" <?=(in_array('4',$childarr))?('checked'):('');?>> 4<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="children_pref[]" value="5" <?=(in_array('5',$childarr))?('checked'):('');?>> 5<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="children_pref[]" value="6" <?=(in_array('6',$childarr))?('checked'):('');?>> 6 or more<br>
```

Comment: How are you storing the checkbox values in the database? From where `$invoice['basket']['fruit']` and `$basket['fruit']` came? Please include the relevant PHP code.

Comment: Sorry - Playing around with my pseudocode and copied the wrong code, updated with actual code

Comment: You should only need to pass the array values to SQL.  You don't then need to retrieve those same values back from SQL because you already have the values.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's much better if you simply save a string containing the values separated by commas in your database. Something like `Apples,Bananas,Oranges` or `Apples,Oranges` obviously this will be set by the user selecting the checkboxes.

In your code you would simply iterate through your post array and concatenate the values creating a new variable with a string containing the values I exampled before. I'll call such variable `$my_selected_fruits` just so I can use it in the SQL query I'll example below.

To get them from the database later will only need `$fruits = explode(",", $db_array)` where `$db_array` will be `Apples,Bananas,Oranges` (or whatever there is stored in the database) and this will output:

```
echo $fruits[0]; // Apples
echo $fruits[1]; // Bananas
echo $fruits[2]; // Oranges
```

Of course, in real code you'll use this data differently, most probably looping through it.

So your SQL query will be something like:

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `database` SET `fruits`='$my_selected_fruits'");
```

In other words, a very simple and basic SQL query.

**- EDIT -**

I don't know exactly why you are trying to do this, but since you insist, I now find it better to just create a JSON object and save it on the database. You don't need to know JSON, fortunately, because you'll only need it to save it in a TEXT column.

So using `json_encode()` you would create a JSON object like the following one and save it in the database (it's an example, depending on your array, it will be encoded differently, you don't need to worry about this JSON):

```
[
    {
        0: {
            "user": "user1",
            "checkbox": "checked"
        },
        1: {
            "user": "user2",
            "checkbox": ""
        },
        2: {
            "user": "user3",
            "checkbox": ""
        },
        3: {
            "user": "user4",
            "checkbox": "checked"
        }
    }
]
```

Then, you retrieve this and save it in a variable which you will then encode back to a PHP array using `json_decode($var, true)`.

After that, you can play with your PHP array again, for example, exploding it.

Comment: Sounds simple - the real fun that I am trying to get accomplished is how to push & pull the checkbox data along with the array

Comment: @Steven Maybe I misunderstood your question? Actually I now see that you updated the code and it has nothing to do with fruits, even though it doesn't change the logic. So you are trying to send the array and save it to the database as is?

Comment: I want to save the array to the db as User1, User 2 with checkbox values as 1:0(checked or unchecked,"), and also call the same data(User1, unchecked, User2, checked)(the checkbox data is based on user selection)  the array eill have around 10values, and include checkboxes

Comment: Ohh, now I see. Well, you can do this with JSON most likely, because you can save a JSON object as text and then retrieve it, using `json_encode()` to generate the object to save in the database and `json_decode()` to convert it back to a PHP array. So you can save a PHP array with several indexes (1 to 10) and their values will be another set of arrays with `'user'=>'user1'` and `'checkbox'=>'0'` (or 1). Am I making myself clear?

Comment: I want to stick to just PHP, I know there is a way of doing it with just PHP - I have researched and found a hundred ways of ALMOST doing it, but falling just short.  Right now I am looking at the "explode" attribute - it looks promising, but I am having issues(new to php).  Eventually I will figure it out and post, unless someone beats me to it :D

Comment: I see, so you're trying to do something that's never done but you know it can be done, isn't it that?. Well, I'm most certainly sure you'll find a way, but from the coding point of view, it won't help you at all probably. I now think that my answer doesn't work for you, but the JSON thing might be the solution because it lets you save more info all together. In any case, I'll update with this option too.

Comment: please see web code - its really close-  I just have to figure out how to save the data in the right format so that I can explode it later as demonstrated.  Thanks!

Comment: The only way to do that is creating a string. That's how explode works. So just convert it into a string. I really don't know what you have found by the way. I just would never have come across with your idea.

Comment: Sorry, I am an idiot w/PHP apparently - how would I convert it to a string?

Comment: What do you want to convert to a string? You have this: `$childarr = explode(",", $row["children_pref"]);` in your code. So `$row["children_pref"]` should already be a string. Such column should be set to VARCHAR or TEXT or whatever string-equivalent datatype you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99230/discussion-between-steven-and-zeke).